# Is there any free, single-word wordlist with CLAWS7 part-of-speech tags?

Tags: english, corpora, parts-of-speech, dictionary

I am looking for a wordlist which includes single-word entries and their part-of-speech tags in UCREL CLAWS7 format.

The list must be comprised of scientifically collected data, for example words collected from COCA or BNC data.

Ideally, the list will also include frequency data.

Here is an example of the type of thing I am looking for: http://www.wordfrequency.info/100k.asp

Comment: Which language?

Comment: @lemontree CLAWS7 suggests English, because it is a pos tagset for English.

Comment: Why don't you do it by yourself? The BNC is downloadable and you can feed it into your favourite corpus processing tool (or write a simple script)  to extract such a wordlist.

Comment: Yes, it is in English. The problem is my inability to afford a license. I operate outside of academia and so I cannot access the download link via Shibboleth. This also means that I cannot view the data in order to determine which software would be appropriate, or whether it would provide me with an extensive list, due to ambiguity resulting from automation.

Comment: In case it helps to clarify, I would like a compiled list in a similar format to the 'frequency' results table found here: http://corpus.byu.edu/bnc/

Comment: Another issue is that the version of English used is up-to-date circa 1990. I need it to include terms from a relatively modern corpus like COCA.

The frequency list linked in my question, for example, uses COCA from 2010.

Answer (score 1):

Why are you not making that list yourself?
Take a Corpus that has a CLAWS7 Tagset (e.g. MICASE) and extract a wordlist using for example AntConc or CQPweb. This is not really hard to do and will give you a much better understanding of how to acquire and process linguistic data.
For example if you use CQPweb simply use the position attributes to search for certain word classes etc. and you will be left with a list of words with their tags.

This is an example of how it would look like. You can extract the data and limit the hits. After this you can also make a random sampling to have a random selection.
[image: CQPweb]